# Insert document in mongodb with autoincrement field from java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am trying to insert a document with a sequence number, in one transaction, from java.

Something similar to this:

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
    var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
        {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
        }
    );

    return ret.seq;
}
collection.insert({
    number: getNextSequence("userid"),
    name: "Some Name"
});
```

Is it possible to do this from java? Preferably with the official java driver.

Answer (score 5):

Following the documentation for [creating an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/), we adapt it to be used in Java with the [Java MongoDB driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/).

**Example implementation:**

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class TestAutoIncrement {

private final static String DB_NAME = "MyTestDB";
private final static String TEST_COLLECTION = "testCollection";
private final static String COUNTERS_COLLECTION = "countersCollection";

public static DBCollection testCollection;
public static DBCollection countersCollection;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        DB database = mongoClient.getDB(DB_NAME);
        testCollection = database.getCollection(TEST_COLLECTION);
        countersCollection = database.getCollection(COUNTERS_COLLECTION);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (countersCollection.count() == 0) {
        createCountersCollection();
    }

    createTestCollection();
}

public static void createCountersCollection() {

    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.append("_id", "userid");
    document.append("seq", 0);
    countersCollection.insert(document);
}

public static Object getNextSequence(String name) {

    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("_id", name);
    BasicDBObject increase = new BasicDBObject("seq", 1);
    BasicDBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject("$inc", increase);
    DBObject result = countersCollection.findAndModify(searchQuery, null, null,
            false, updateQuery, true, false);

    return result.get("seq");
}

public static void createTestCollection() {

    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.append("_id", getNextSequence("userid"));
    document.append("name", "Sarah");
    testCollection.insert(document);

    document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.append("_id", getNextSequence("userid"));
    document.append("name", "Bob");
    testCollection.insert(document);

    document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.append("_id", getNextSequence("userid"));
    document.append("name", "Alex");
    testCollection.insert(document);
  }

}
```

**Special attention must be paid to the `findAndModify` method**. In the Java MongoDB driver (2.12.4), the method is available with 4 different signatures.
You must use one which lets you pass a `query` object, `update` object and `returnNew` boolean (which has to be set to `true`).

That's because, according to [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/):
***By default, the returned document does not include the modifications made on the update. To return the document with the modifications made on the update, use the new option.***

We need to return the document with the modifications made on the update.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot perform this in one transaction, and even your javascript example performs a findAndModify before performing the insert.

If you're looking to insert documents into a collection with an increasing count of documents from that collection you can use the count method and add 1.

```
    final DBCollection col = db.getCollection("myCollection");
    col.insert(new BasicDBObject("number", col.count() + 1));
```

Or by using a separate "counters" collection with a findAndModify() in lieu of count()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("testCollection");
// create an increment query
DBObject modifier = new BasicDBObject("counter", 1);
DBObject incQuery = new BasicDBObject("$inc", modifier);
// create a search query
DBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("name", "someName");
// increment a counter value atomically
DBObject res = collection.findAndModify(searchQuery, incQuery);
```

Comment: This will update the same object, i need something that inserts new objects were one field is incremented by one for each new object. they should look like this {name:"name", number:1},{name="name", number:2},{name="someothername",number:3}

Answer (score 1):

just as Alex wrote but this code is appropriate for 3.x versions

```
import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;

public class TestAutoIncrement {

     private final static String DB_NAME = "MyTestDB";
     private final static String TEST_COLLECTION = "testCollection";
     private final static String COUNTERS_COLLECTION = "countersCollection";

     private static MongoCollection<Document> testCollection;
     private static MongoCollection<Document> countersCollection;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(DB_NAME);
    testCollection = database.getCollection(TEST_COLLECTION);
    countersCollection = database.getCollection(COUNTERS_COLLECTION);

    if (countersCollection.count() == 0) {
        createCountersCollection();
    }

    createTestCollection();
    mongoClient.close();
}

public static void createCountersCollection() {

    Document document = new Document();
    document.append("_id", "userid");
    document.append("seq", 1);
    countersCollection.insertOne(document);
}

public static Object getNextSequence(String name) {

    Document searchQuery = new Document("_id", name);
    Document increase = new Document("seq", 1);
    Document updateQuery = new Document("$inc", increase);
    Document result = countersCollection.findOneAndUpdate(searchQuery, updateQuery);

    return result.get("seq");
}

public static void createTestCollection() {

    Document document = new Document();
    document.append("_id", getNextSequence("userid"));
    document.append("name", "Dinah");
    testCollection.insertOne(document);

    document = new Document();
    document.append("_id", getNextSequence("userid"));
    document.append("name", "Jonny");
    testCollection.insertOne(document);

    document = new Document();
    document.append("_id", getNextSequence("userid"));
    document.append("name", "Brody");
    testCollection.insertOne(document);
}

}
```