# Mongo 3.4 - insert with auto increment seq no from Java in single transaction

Tags: java, mongodb

I would like to insert documents in a collection with an auto incrementing sequence number in one transaction from Java with Mongo 3.4.

This has been asked before -see link below - however none of the solutions posted there appear to execute in one transaction. They all fetch the next sequence number as one (atomic) transaction, then use it in the insert in the 2nd transaction.

[Insert document in mongodb with autoincrement field from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631396/insert-document-in-mongodb-with-autoincrement-field-from-java)

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need an absolute global auto increment number? This creates a bottleneck since you must have a central sequence generator. Also what would happen if the generator crashed or cannot communicate with the app? How would you process insertion or reseed the central generator again?

Comment: The true answer is that we have an app which reaches out to "get the next sequence number" already in a separate transaction, and we are trying to tighten this into one transaction to avoid race conditions. The sequence number is used to order all notifications in a single RSS-like feed (for integration with a 3rd party), which have to be globally ordered consistently to work.

Comment: But my situation aside the general answer is that I feel like it's a common enough ask, supported by many database technologies.

Comment: I believe what you're trying to do goes "against the grain" for MongoDB. It's not that it can't be done, but it will overcomplicate your design. What you're doing is normal in a monolithic database where everything is contained within a single server, while MongoDB was designed with a distributed model, where your data is spanned across many different servers. As a matter of fact, MongoDB removed the tutorial for autoincrement field from the docs in [DOCS-7991](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-7991).

Comment: Having said that, MongoDB 4.0 supports transactions within a replica set (see https://www.mongodb.com/transactions), so what you want can be done in a single transaction. From the answer you linked, you can wrap the calls to `findAndModify` and `insertOne` within a single transaction so the whole operation will be atomic. If you need further help with this, please post the non-atomic code you're using and I'll try to see if it can be wrapped inside a transaction.

Comment: Thank you @kevinadi :) We are looking at Mongo 4.0 but it won't come any time soon for us. I appreciate what you are saying though, and I agree. But for now, with Mongo 3.4 and the data setup we currently have, together with requirements favouring consistency over throughput, we will fall back on a global lock enforcing a "single writer" at the application level, which then can increment sequence ids at leisure in a separate transaction safe in knowledge that nothing else can be doing that at the same time.